# Get baseActivity of running task in Lollipop

Tags: android

Please help me to change this code for android L. Function `getRunningTask` is deprecated in API 21.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);     

  for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
    if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName()))
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> alltasks= activityManager.getAppTasks();

for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : alltasks) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stackId: " + task.getTaskInfo().stackId);
}
```

Comment: Error Cannot resolve symbol 'stackId'. Can I use task.getTaskInfo().baseActivity?

Comment: check the official Docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html 
 it depends what function you need in your app !!